# What are Sitemap content tags?

Tags: seo, sitemap, web-crawlers

i have recently generated sitemap for google.

I included following loc, lastmod, changefreq. My site is in two languages. Do i need to add some other tags for specifying languages too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [see the format here](http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php). There currently is no tag for specifying language.